# How to import a changing variable from one script to another?

Tags: python, file, variables, import

I have this variable called speed which is the output of my python file that tracks the speed of someone's face. But the variable keeps changing because the speed at the face is moving is changing. And I want to `import` this variable that keeps changing into another python script. Any ideas on how to do this?

here is some code

```py
    _, frame = cap.read()
    
    
    intialTime = time.time()
    face_width_in_frame, Faces, FC_X, FC_Y = face_data(
        frame, True, Distance_level)
    
    for (face_x, face_y, face_w, face_h) in Faces:
        if face_width_in_frame != 0:

            Distance = Distance_finder(
                Focal_length_found, Known_width, face_width_in_frame)
            DistanceList.append(Distance)
            avergDistnce = averageFinder(DistanceList, 6)
            
            roundedDistance = round((avergDistnce*0.0254), 2)
            
            Distance_level = int(Distance)
            if intialDisntace != 0:

                changeDistance = Distance - intialDisntace
                distanceInMeters = changeDistance * 0.0254

                velocity = speedFinder(distanceInMeters, changeInTime)

                speedList.append(velocity)

                averageSpeed = averageFinder(speedList, 6)
            
            intialDisntace = avergDistnce

            changeInTime = time.time() - intialTime
            

            cv2.line(frame, (25, 45), (80, 45), (ORANGE), 26)
            cv2.line(frame, (25, 45), (80, 45), (GREEN), 20)
            if averageSpeed < 0:
                averageSpeed = averageSpeed * -
                newaverageSpeed = averageSpeed*39.57                        
            cv2.putText(
                frame, f"Speed: {round(averageSpeed,2)} in/s", (30, 50), fonts, 0.5, BLACK, 2)

            cv2.putText(frame, f"Distance {roundedDistance*39.57} inches",
                        (face_x-6, face_y-6), fonts, 0.5, (BLACK), 2)
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    out.write(frame)

    if cv2.waitKey() == ord("q"):
        break

cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I want to take the output variables averageSpeed,roundedDistance and import them into another script. How should I do this?

Comment: import the function that returns this variable to the other python file and run the function from there

Comment: Show us ur code

Comment: `import my_module; print(my_module.variable)`???

Comment: Yes, I have some ideas. What's changing the variable (i.e. what's making it change)?

Comment: Yes it is the output of a function that is actively running. And I want that to be able to get those outputs into another python file

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? Just a little something I can use for testing.

Comment: Sure let me update the question

Comment: I was hoping from something I could actually *run*. What variable is changing? What function is changing it? What calls that function or is it running in another thread?

Comment: You can try a loop that keeps adds +1 to X, that would be close to the reproduction of the Code. I cant give you a sample rn But i can add it later

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can do it merely by referencing the changing variable through the module's name. 
This is what I'm saying:

`main.py`:

```
from time import sleep, time
import other_script

start = time()

while time()-start < 10:  # Loop for around 10 seconds.
    print(other_script.speed)
    sleep(1)

other_script.cancel_updates()
print('fini')
```

`other_script.py`:

```
from threading import Timer

speed = 0
timer = None

def update_speed(delay=0.5):
    global speed, timer

    speed += 1
    timer = Timer(delay, update_speed)  # Do it again after delay.
    timer.start()

def cancel_updates():
    timer.cancel()

update_speed(1.0)  # Start updates after 1 sec.
```

Output:

```
1
1
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
fini
```